# How do I can change the color of my span colon along my timer numbers?

Tags: javascript, html, css, timer

My timer and all works well but the span that was created to make a colon between the timer doesn't change color along with my numbers.

I tried `var colon = document.getElementById(":");`
Still didn't work.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Countdown</title>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 var direction = 'down';
 var mins = 1;
 var secs = mins * 60;

 function colorchange(minutes, seconds) {
 var minutes = document.getElementById('minutes');
 var seconds = document.getElementById('seconds');


 var color;
 if (direction == 'up') {
 color = 'black';
 } else if (secs <= 30) {
 color = 'red';
 } else if (secs <= 59) {
  color = 'orange';
  }
  minutes.style.color = seconds.style.color = color
   }

   function getminutes() {
  // minutes is seconds divided by 60, rounded down
   mins = Math.floor(secs / 60);
   return ("0" + mins).substr(-2);
   }

    function getseconds() {
   // take mins remaining (as seconds) away from total seconds remaining
    return ("0" + (secs - Math.round(mins * 60))).substr(-2);
    }

   function countdown() {
   setInterval(function() {
   var minutes = document.getElementById('minutes');
   var seconds = document.getElementById('seconds');

    minutes.value = getminutes();
    seconds.value = getseconds();
   colorchange(minutes, seconds);

    if (direction == 'down') {
  secs--;
  if (secs <= 0) {
    direction = 'up';
  }
} else if (direction == 'up') {
  secs++;
 }
 }, 1000);
 }


 countdown();
 </script>
 </head>
  <body>

 <div id="timer" style="width: 90%;">
  <input id="minutes" type="text" style="width: 90%; border: none; background-color:none; font-size: 300px; font-weight: bold; position: fixed; bottom: 30%;right: -2%;">
  <input id="seconds" type="text" style="width: 90%; border: none; background-color:none; font-size: 300px; font-weight: bold; position: fixed; bottom: 30%;right: -42%;">
 <span style="width: 90%; border: none; background-color:none; font-size: 300px; font-weight: bold; position: fixed; bottom: 30%; padding-left: 42%;">:       </span>
 </div>
 <script>

  </script>
```

Comment: Give the `<span>` a proper id value and use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give id to span say `id="divider"`, so span becomes:

```
<span id="divide" style="width: 90%; border: none; background-color:none; font-size: 300px; font-weight: bold; position: fixed; bottom: 30%; padding-left: 42%;">:       </span>
```

Then use in your code to get the element like:

```
var colon = document.getElementById('divide');
```

Then change its color as:

```
minutes.style.color = seconds.style.color = colon.style.color = color
```

See the plunkr: "http://plnkr.co/edit/IGAQrjIjj4fowUi6BPxs?p=preview"